# How to make Boost contracts visible to clients

Tags: c++, boost, c++20

I'm looking at using Boost contracts to implement DBC in C++, but I consider a key part of DBC is that both parties to the contract need to be able to *see* the contract, and I'm having trouble with that. The Boost contract code seems to go in the definition of a function, but - ideally - the client only sees the declaration.

I think I've found a workaround for straightforward functions: put the definition in the header file but only with the contract information and a call to a private implementation which is only declared in the header (`newParent` in the example below) - I'm open to better ideas, though.

My problem comes with constructors, especially if I need to pass things to a parent constructor (and those things don't have default constructors). It seems I either have to expose that process in the header or I hide the contract in the cpp file. Or, the best I've come up with yet, it to use a factory method, where I can expose the contract in the header and defer implementation to the cpp file as I'm doing with other functions.

Is there a better way? Here's some example code.

In `test.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/contract.hpp>
#include <memory>

class Parent {
    std::string m_name;
public:
    Parent(std::string name);
};

class Child : Parent {
    std::shared_ptr<Parent> m_parent;
    inline void newParent_impl(std::shared_ptr<Parent> parent);

public:
    Child(std::string name, std::shared_ptr<Parent> parent);

    void newParent(std::shared_ptr<Parent> parent) {
        boost::contract::check c = boost::contract::function()
            .precondition([&] {
            BOOST_CONTRACT_ASSERT(parent);
            });
        newParent_impl(parent);
    }
};
```

in `test.cpp`

```
#include "test.h"

Parent::Parent(std::string name)
{
    m_name = name;
}

void Child::newParent_impl(std::shared_ptr<Parent> parent)
{
    m_parent = parent;
}

Child::Child(std::string name, std::shared_ptr<Parent> parent): Parent{name}, m_parent{parent}
{
    // I don't want this hidden from the client!
    boost::contract::check c = boost::contract::function()
        .precondition([&] {
        BOOST_CONTRACT_ASSERT(parent);
            });
}
```

By the way, it's *many* years since I last looked at C++ - I've forgotten half of what I knew, and the other half is now obsolete, so please forgive me if I'm missing something obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/contract/doc/html/boost_contract/contract_programming_overview.html#boost_contract.contract_programming_overview.constructor_calls), it's anathema to use `boost::contract::function()` to check contracts in a constructor. You ought to use `boost::contract::constructor()` instead.

But then you'll find that `boost::contract::precondition()` fails to compile, because preconditions in constructors really need to run before the base/member initializers run.

Therefore Boost Contracts gives you [`constructor_precondition`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/contract/doc/html/boost/contract/constructor_precondition.html) to put in your classes' base list.

> Note 1: Be sure to read all of the subtler guidelines in the documentation.

> Note 2: Using `function()` will never check (static) class invariants,  and if you have them you need to at least inherit from `constructor_precondition` to have them automatically checked from the constructor.

#### Applying It

First I simplified sample to remove your workaround:

> *There are some minor improvements (move semantics and member-initializer list use; the `inline` keyword was a lie because the definition was never available at the invocation, some renames to avoid confusion)*

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e3cd0b4e3e190ba)**

- File `test.h`

  ```
   // test.h
   #pragma once

   #include <boost/contract.hpp>
   #include <memory>

   class Node {
       std::string m_name;

     public:
       Node(std::string name);
   };

   class Child : Node {
       std::shared_ptr<Node> m_parent;

     public:
       Child(std::string name, std::shared_ptr<Node> parent);

       void changeParent(std::shared_ptr<Node> parent)
       {
           boost::contract::check c =
               boost::contract::function().precondition([&] { BOOST_CONTRACT_ASSERT(parent); });
           m_parent = parent;
       }
   };
  ```
- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   // test.cpp
   #include "test.h"

   Node::Node(std::string name) : m_name(std::move(name))
   {
   }

   Child::Child(std::string name, std::shared_ptr<Node> parent) : Node{std::move(name)}, m_parent{parent}
   {
       // I don't want this hidden from the client!
       boost::contract::check c = //
           boost::contract::function().precondition([&] {
               BOOST_CONTRACT_ASSERT(parent);
           });
   }

   // main.cpp

   int main()
   {
       auto  p = std::make_shared<Node>("parent");
       Child child("child", p);

       p = std::make_shared<Node>("foster");
       child.changeParent(p);
   }
  ```

Which [works cleanly](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e3cd0b4e3e190ba)

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -fsanitize=undefined,address && ./a.out
```

### Enter `constructor_precondition`

We'll keep using it with private methods to hide the actual implementation.

In fact, I'd probably move as much implementation as possible into an `Impl` type: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c860682efbc2971)**

- File `test.h`

  ```
   // test.h
   #pragma once

   #include <boost/contract.hpp>
   #include <memory>
   namespace bc = boost::contract;

   class Node {
       std::string m_name;

     public:
       Node(std::string name);
   };

   class Child
       : private bc::constructor_precondition<Child>
       , public Node
   {
       struct Impl {
           std::shared_ptr<Node> m_parent;
           Impl(std::shared_ptr<Node>);
           void changeParent(std::shared_ptr<Node>);
       } _impl;

     public:
       Child(std::string name, std::shared_ptr<Node> parent)
           : bc::constructor_precondition<Child>([&] { BOOST_CONTRACT_ASSERT(parent); })
           , Node(std::move(name))
           , _impl(std::move(parent)) {}

       void changeParent(std::shared_ptr<Node> parent) {
           bc::check c = bc::function().precondition([&] { BOOST_CONTRACT_ASSERT(parent); });

           _impl.changeParent(std::move(parent));
       }
   };
  ```
- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   // test.cpp
   #include "test.h"

   Node::Node(std::string name) : m_name(std::move(name)) {}

   Child::Impl::Impl(std::shared_ptr<Node> parent) : m_parent(std::move(parent)) {}
   void Child::Impl::changeParent(std::shared_ptr<Node> parent) { m_parent = std::move(parent); }

   // main.cpp
   int main() {
       auto  p = std::make_shared<Node>("parent");
       Child child("child", p);

       p = std::make_shared<Node>("foster");
       child.changeParent(p);
   }
  ```

In fact I'd even consider removing the duplication of the precondition by writing the constructor like this instead: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f500a66b439a19d5)**

- File `test.h`

  ```
   // test.h
   #pragma once

   #include <boost/contract.hpp>
   #include <memory>
   namespace bc = boost::contract;

   class Node {
       std::string m_name;

     public:
       Node(std::string name);
   };

   class Child : Node
   {
       struct Impl {
           std::shared_ptr<Node> m_parent;
           void changeParent(std::shared_ptr<Node>);
       } _impl;

     public:
       Child(std::string name, std::shared_ptr<Node> parent) : Node(std::move(name)) {
           changeParent(std::move(parent));
       }

       void changeParent(std::shared_ptr<Node> parent) {
           bc::check c = bc::function().precondition([&] { BOOST_CONTRACT_ASSERT(parent); });

           _impl.changeParent(std::move(parent));
       }
   };
  ```
- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   // test.cpp
   #include "test.h"

   Node::Node(std::string name) : m_name(std::move(name)) {}
   void Child::Impl::changeParent(std::shared_ptr<Node> parent) { m_parent = std::move(parent); }

   // main.cpp
   int main() {
       auto  p = std::make_shared<Node>("parent");
       Child child("child", p);

       p = std::make_shared<Node>("foster");
       child.changeParent(p);
   }
  ```

Comment: Many *many* thanks for your comprehensive reply. I'm glad the way I was doing it was anathema because, well, it *felt* klunky. I'm not sure I understand why `inline` was a lie, but hey, it's been a long while and I guess that's another question.